# Position absolute and position relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am confused about position absolute and relative in CSS.

```html
<div id="container" style="position:"relative">
  <button style="position:"absolute"; left:10px;" >
</div>
```

In the above example, when I set position as absolute and left as 10px to button means it doesn't takes the position from browser window. Instead of this, it takes position from parent div (container) because container position is relative. Why?

When I set position absolute to any element it takes the position from browser window only. Why it checks the parent element and then positioning.

When I set position relative to any element means that time it will position based on parent element.

```html
<p>Paragraph 1.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
<p style="position: relative;left: 2em;">Paragraph 3.</p>
```

In the above example, the third paragraph will be positioned 3em from the left side of the container element.

I have researched following links.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa061307.htm

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

`absolute` → takes position from browser window

`relative` → takes position from parent of an element

Comment: You are correct. If you place an absolutely-positioned element inside of a relatively-positioned element, the inner element positioning is based on the parent. Not exactly sure *why* this is the case, but this is how it works. Also remember that absolute positioning takes an object out of the flow; the relative parent just helps establish the 0,0 coordinates, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element the position of which isn't static. If such element is not found, the containing block is html element.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute**

Positioned relative the first parent element that is `relative` or `absolute` (defaults to html/browser window) - meaning that having a `relative` parent, causes all child elements to be positioned relative to that element when using `absolute`

**Relative**

Positioned relative to it's original static position (parent not involved) - can be used to slightly move an element from it's current position, *without affecting the elements' layout*

**Fixed**

Depending on your usage requirements, another option is `position:fixed` which keeps the item positioned relative to the browser window, regardless of parent styling (useful for modal windows, as the element stays where it is, even when scrolling)

**Extra reading:** http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/